# Caching Data in a Service

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm very new to rxjs and async programming in general.

When a component requests data from my service, I only want to hit my API if I don't already have the data.  Something like the following pseudo code:

```js
if (!data) {
  data = this.getDataFromApi();
}
return data;
```

This is how you would do it in a synchronous way in a language like C#.  Basically, I would only every have to call getDataFromApi() once.

How might I achieve the same thing in Angular/rxjs?

Let the abuse begin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the ways to cache your data -

```
export class YourCacheService {

  data: any; //set type of the data as per your app
  constructor() { }

  getData(): Observable<any> {
    //if data exist then simply return the data wrapped in an observable
    if (this.data) {
      return of(data);
    } else {
      //otherwise return the response of the API which will have the data
      //and save the data in this.data 
      return this.getDataFromApi()
                 .pipe(
                   tap(data => {
                    this.data = data;
                    }
                  );
    }
  }
}
```

Now consumer of the `yourcacheService.getData()` will subscribe to the observable returned by `getData()` to get the data like this -

```
yourcacheService.getData()
                  .subscribe(data => {
                    //do whatever you want to do with the data
                  });
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you.